# If statement on split list not working python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list which I'm running through a for loop. And then trying to compare certain elements of the list with a if statement. My issue is that the if statement is not working. I have printed the value and do not see any reason why it should not go into the `if` statement. I have also performed a `strip()` and casted the variable to a `str(var)` which does not work. I assume it has something to do list which I'm unable to figure out, please help

Below is a portion of my code. The problematic if statement is the line looking for VMWARE

```
for i in PORTSB:
    if i.startswith('CL'):
        HOSTGRP_CMD = '/HORCM/usr/bin/raidcom get host_grp -port {0} -IH{1}|grep -v PORT'.format(i, HORCM)
        HOSTGRP = subprocess.check_output([HOSTGRP_CMD], shell=True, universal_newlines=True).split()
        for j in range(len(HOSTGRP)):
            if HOSTGRP[j] == HOST:
                PORTS.append([HOSTGRP[j - 2]])
                HSD.append([HOSTGRP[j - 2] + '-' + HOSTGRP[j - 1]])
                HSD_N.append([HOSTGRP[j]])
                HOST_M.append([HOSTGRP[j + 2]])
                if HOSTGRP[j + 2].strip() == 'WMWARE_EX':
                    HOST_MN.append([33])
                elif HOSTGRP[j + 2].strip() == 'WMWARE':
                    HOST_MN.append([1])
                elif HOSTGRP[j + 2].strip() == 'AIX':
                    HOST_MN.append([15])
                elif HOSTGRP[j + 2].strip() == 'SOLARIS':
                    HOST_MN.append([9])
                elif HOSTGRP[j + 2].strip() == 'WIN_EX':
                    HOST_MN.append([44])
                elif HOSTGRP[j + 2].strip() == 'WIN':
                    HOST_MN.append([12])
                elif HOSTGRP[j + 2].strip() == 'LINUX':
                    HOST_MN.append([0])
```

Comment: You may want to use dictionary instead of that if-elif block.

Comment: This code could use some major cleanup; what are you trying to accomplish with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you misspelled `'VMWARE'` as `'WMWARE'`. You also have `'WMWARE_EX'` instead of `'VMWARE_EX'`.